# Material-UI : Juxtapose tab if screen if big enough

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to find a way to change my layout from two tab on a small screen to two div side by side if the screen is big enough.

I'm surprised because the doc describe what I think is exactly what I need but I don't know how to do it :

[image]

https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#whiteframes

Thanks by advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just used two different rendering depending of the screen size so the problem was handled on the react size instead of the material ui